# Handling TOP in A CASE-WHEN-THEN select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am having a problem to resolve a SELECT CASE using TOP.

Should I mention I'm quite new to this ? :D
Also this is my first post on Stackoverflow. Hi !

I want to fill one column of informations from two tables :

Table 1 : Column 1 contains data I want to use

Table 1 : Column 2 is a join

Table 2 : Column 1 contains data I want to use

Table 2 : Column 2 is a join

So :

Table 1 Column 1 contains letters (D M and T) and empty spaces.

Table 2 Column 1 contains words ('Rolls' 'Transfers' 'Delivery')

I'm trying to fill my column using the following conditions :

- When column T1.C1 contains D, M or T, write D M or T.
- When column T1.C1 is empty, look at column T2.C1 :

  - If column T1.C1 contains 'Rolls', write 'R'
  - Else don't write anything

Things get ugly really fast for me because the info I want from column B requires a TOP to be used.

THe best I could get so far is **Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'From'**.

Here is my code so far.
Any suggestions ?

```
SELECT

(CASE T1.C1
WHEN 'D'
    THEN 'D'
WHEN 'M'
    THEN 'M'
WHEN 'T'
    THEN 'T'
WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 T2.C1 FROM T2 WHERE T1.C2=T2.C2)
    THEN 'R'
ELSE
    ''
END) as my_data,

FROM T1
```

Comment: Remove the comma after `my_data`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to find a simpler way to write this, something along the lines of:

```
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   C1 ,
                        C2 ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY C2 ORDER BY col ) rn
               FROM     Table2
             )
    SELECT  CASE WHEN T1.C1 = '' THEN LEFT(T2.C1, 1)
                 ELSE T1.C1
            END AS my_data
    FROM    Table1 T1
            LEFT OUTER JOIN cte T2 ON T1.C2 = T2.C2
                                      AND T2.rn = 1
```

You haven't posted your table schema, so this may need to be adjusted.